# show input tag for each selected dropdown with validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

here's my code for dropdown and input field's

```
   <div>
        <select id="scl">
                <option value="10">Ten</option>
                <option value="7">Seven</option>
                <option value="4">Four</option>
         </select>
    </div>

<form>
    <div class="10 box" ><input type="number"  required></div>
    <div class="7 box" hidden><input type="numbe" required></div>
    <div class="4 box" hidden><input type="number" required></div>
      <input type="submit" >
 </form>
```

here's my jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scl").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

it does not submit my form.

it show's and hide the input field for a specific drop down (i.e. if option 10 is selected it shows input field 10) but my problem is how can I remove validation from remaining two fields so that I can submit form

**I need validation for selected field only.**

any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of adding "required" over here -

You can add "required" to the input field after this $("." + optionValue).show();

Use this line to add required prop to this field:
$("." + optionValue).prop('required',true);

And subsequently set the others as false.